# How to use Zend Validators to validate the presence of a boolean value

Tags: php, validation, zend-framework

I'm struggling with Zend Validators right now. Using Zend 1.12 and no, I can't upgrade. I'm trying and failing to validate that a boolean value is being passed, and nothing else. So either true or false would validate, but null wont. Seems simple but here's what I've run into so far:

Using setRequired() - false fails but null validates

```
$myForm = new \Zend_Form();

$myElement = new \Zend_Form_Element('isPrimary');

// set up validation
$myElement->setRequired(true);

$myForm->addElement($myElement);

$trueResult  = $myForm->isValid(array('isPrimary' => true));  // true
$falseResult = $myForm->isValid(array('isPrimary' => false)); // false (WTF?)
$nullResult  = $myForm->isValid(array('isPrimary' => null));  // false
```

Using Zend_Validator_InArray() -

```
...

// set up validation
$myElement->addValidator(
    new \Zend_Validate_InArray(
        array(
            'haystack' => array(true, false)
        )
    )
);

$myForm->addElement($myElement);

$trueResult  = $myForm->isValid(array('isPrimary' => true));  // true
$falseResult = $myForm->isValid(array('isPrimary' => false)); // true
$nullResult  = $myForm->isValid(array('isPrimary' => null));  // true (WTF?)
```

... with strict turned on -

```
$trueResult  = $myForm->isValid(array('isPrimary' => true));  // true
$falseResult = $myForm->isValid(array('isPrimary' => false)); // true
$nullResult  = $myForm->isValid(array('isPrimary' => null));  // true (WTF?)
```

Using Zend_Validate_Callback() -

```
...
$myElement->addValidator(
    new \Zend_Validate_Callback(
        function ($value) {
            return is_bool($value);
        }
    )
);

$myForm->addElement($myElement);

$trueResult  = $myForm->isValid(array('isPrimary' => true));  // true
$falseResult = $myForm->isValid(array('isPrimary' => false)); // true
$nullResult  = $myForm->isValid(array('isPrimary' => null));  // true (AHHHHHGGGGGHHH)
```

After some debugging, it appears the callback is never even called when I pass in null and just validates anyway. What is going on with these validators?

EDIT:

Also tried \Zend_Validate_NotEmpty -

```
$trueResult  = $myForm->isValid(array('isPrimary' => true));  // true
$falseResult = $myForm->isValid(array('isPrimary' => false)); // false
$nullResult  = $myForm->isValid(array('isPrimary' => null));  // true
```

using \Zend_Validate_NotEmpty::BOOLEAN - true, false, true

using \Zend_Validate_NotEmpty::BOOLEAN and NULL - true, false, true

using \Zend_Validate_NotEmpty::PHP - true, false, true

Answer (score 0):

I managed to get it working using a filter before the validator. If anyone runs into this problem, here is one solution:

```
$myElement->addFilter(new \Zend_Filter_Callback('is_bool'))
    ->addValidator(
        new \Zend_Validate_NotEmpty(\Zend_Validate_NotEmpty::BOOLEAN)
    );
```

Zend_Filter_Boolean didn't seem to work right either (probably would with the right options) so I just used the callback to is_bool().

I would love some insight as to why the validators weren't even being called on the null value if anyone knows.

Comment: Callback is not called because by default filters have "AllowEmpty" set to false - null value is considered empty so callback will not be called. You need to set BreakOnFailure to false to call your callback but it will still fail.